# Is my bonsai dead?

Tags: bonsai

I got this bonsai a few months ago as a gift. I leave it in a place where it gets a lot of sun. I haven’t been home for a while and forgot to have someone water it for about a month. Is my bonsai dead? The leaves are falling off but I’m hoping it’s still savable. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: This is one of those "supermarket" bonsai's, right? The gravel glued in on the top into a hard surface? Don't buy these, they almost never live. They are usually very poorly done with poor soil and badly trimmed roots, just slammed into the dish.

Comment: The majority of bonsai specimens are trees and invariably, people think that if they are dinky in size they can be treated like houseplants and kept indoors.

Now, your tree is most certainly one that goes outside. Do you normally keep it outside  and just brought it in to photograph or have you been keeping it indoors please?

Leaving a large plant, shrub or tree planted outside would easily survive without human watering for a month but not a bonsai which has a quite tiny amount of substrate to hold any water beyond rain water if outdoors. 

I regret your tree is probably going to die.

Comment: Your plant is green, a good sign. Water gently and mist daily in the brightest light without direct sun until growing again (= intensive care). A bonsai is a museum piece -- ignoring it for a month says a neighbor may be a better parent.